# Cannot create a foreign key ERROR 1215 (HY000) foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql

```
 create table a  
 ( a varchar(10),  
 c varchar(10),  
 d varchar(10),  
 primary key (a,c));
```

table a was created successfully...

```
create table b  
 (
 a varchar(10),  
 c varchar(10),  
 d varchar(10),  
 primary key(a),  
 foreign key(a) references a(a),  
 foreign key(c) references a(c)
 );
```

ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint

cannot able to create table b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
foreign key(a,c) references a(a,c)
```

Also, it is a good idea to name your constraints:

```
constraint <name> foreign key(a,c) references a(a,c)
```